# is it possible to implement payment gateway using WebBrowser control in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to implement  payment gateway inside my WindowsPhone App , Will MicroSoft allow me to use WebBrowser control to handle payments?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the [certification requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184843%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that would prevent you from doing this.

Comment: Hi Matt, what do you mean, can't we implement payment gateway inside app, is there any way to do so?

Comment: @Noorul You can do this. There is nothing to stop you.

Comment: Hi @Matt can you please look at this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09c8f54a-c16c-43bf-8689-cdbf96e8312d/app-certification-process-failed-while-app-submission) , my app failed certification process, because of payment gateway, Can you please help.I am not getting a clear idea to solve this problem.Thanks for your reply.